# onActivityResult não retorna o setResult

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

Oque acontece é que tenho uma Activity Cliente onde tenho 2 botoes, um de cadastro e outro de consulta, quando chamo o de cadastro abre uma Activity com um TabHost com 2 fragmentos dentro, na consulta abre uma Activity com listView e tal, porém nela tem 2 botões, um para eu editar e outro para cadastrar um novo Cliente (não me pergunte o por que, meu patrão pediu assim), a minha dificuldade é a seguinte, 
estou na tela de cadastro, vou buscar o bairro e chamo o startActivityForResult, se chamei a tela de cadastro direto do botão de cadastrar o setResult da Consulta de Bairro retorna a Intent, se chamo da Activity de Consulta de Clientes e busco um Bairro, não retorna os valores do setResult.

OBS: uso a mesma activity para Cadastrar e Editar.

chamando o startActivityForResult:

```
private void abrirConsBairro(View view) {
    Button btnPesqBairro = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAbrirBairro);

    btnPesqBairro.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent bairroCons = new Intent(getActivity(), BairroConsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(bairroCons, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Dentro da Consulta de Bairro:

```
public void selecionarBairro(View view) {
    if (listaBairroCons.getCheckedItemPosition() == -1) {
        Mensagens.mensagemCustomizada("Aviso!", "Selecione um Bairro primeiro!", BairroConsActivity.this);
        return;
    }
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("objBairro", objBairro);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(1, i);
    finish();
}
```

onActivityResult da tela de cadastro:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        objCliente.getEndereco().setBairro((Bairro) data.getParcelableExtra("objBairro"));
        edtBairro.setText(objCliente.getEndereco().getBairro().getNome());
        edtMunicipio.setText(objCliente.getEndereco().getBairro().getMunicipio().getNome());
        edtEstado.setText(objCliente.getEndereco().getBairro().getMunicipio().getEstado().getNome());
    }
}
```

OBS²: ultilizo valor 0 e 1 em um atributo para saber quando é cadastro e quando é edição;

Comment: lavaprato, lembrando que o segundo parâmetro do `startActivityForResult` é o `requestCode` e o primeiro parâmetro do `setResult` é o `resultCode`. O que você pode fazer é passar um parâmetro dentro do `Bundle` dizendo se é edição ou criação ao invés de usar 1 e 0.

Comment: Olá Wakim, sim eu compreendo isso, porém o que acontece é que ao chamar o onActivityResult da activity de consulta ele não retorna o setResult, debuguei e vi que o setResult seta certinho os parametros que passo, porém a outra activity não resgata.

Comment: No caso seria o `Intent data` vem nulo ou o `Parcelable` dentro dele vem nulo?

Comment: o Intent está vindo vázio

Comment: Minha sugestão seria usar o próprio `getIntent` ao invés de instanciar um novo e chamar `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)` ao invés de `setResult(1, intent)`.

Comment: não sei pq mas deu certo ^^  vlwz

Comment: Ah, show, vou criar uma resposta para deixar para outros usuários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha sugestão é usar o próprio `getIntent`, mas acredito que seja opcional (vi um código meu que faz diferente e funciona :P), ao invés de criar um novo e setar o `resultCode` como `RESULT_OK`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

intent.putExtra("objBairro", objBairro);

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

É uma boa prática usar o `RESULT_OK`.

Minha outra sugestão é realmente usar o `requestCode` como a flag pra indicar se é edição ou criação.